# How to iterate over a dataframe with a user defined function, 3 arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to determine the cumulative return of each stock in my dataframe based on given dates. I can determine the cumulative return of any given stock using the following function:

```
def cumlative_return(start_date, end_date, ticker):
    cum_return = (portfolio_test.loc[end_date, ticker] / portfolio_test.loc[start_date, ticker]) - 1
    return cum_return
```

where ticker is the column name and the dates are the index.

How can I apply this function to each column of my dataframe? I've tried various for loops and .apply(). Below is the closest I've gotten but I get an error saying there are too many positional arguments:

```
for ticker in portfolio_test:
   portfolio_test.apply(cumlative_return, axis=0, args=['2000-01-03', '2020-07-06', ticker])
```

TypeError: cumlative_return() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Answer (score 0):

Please reference the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply).

```
for ticker in portfolio_test:
```

The purpose of the `apply` method is that *it does the iteration for you*, so you should not have the loop yourself.

```
    portfolio_test.apply(cumlative_return, axis=0, args=['2000-01-03', '2020-07-06', ticker])
```

The `args` that you pass, meanwhile, should be:

> Positional arguments to pass to func **in addition to** the array/series.

(emphasis mine)

The `apply` method will pass the dataframe columns along to `cumlative_return` for you, so you should not specify them in the `args`.

So, all you need or want is:

```
# BTW, `axis=0` is already the default.
portfolio_test.apply(cumlative_return, args=['2000-01-03', '2020-07-06'])
```

Comment: I've tried this but I get a KeyError: '2020-07-06'. Which is weird because when I used this date for the cumulative_return function it works fine. Any date I put in here returns a KeyError. Any ideas?

Comment: So, when `cumlative_return` is called, the `ticker` parameter will be passed a Series that represents one of the columns of your Dataframe. Your existing logic tries to use a global Dataframe and index into it two-dimensionally, expecting `ticker` to identify the column. You'll need to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, but not with apply. The code is as simple as below:

```
for i in portfolio_test:
    print(cumulative_return(i, '2000-01-03', '2020-07-06' ))
```